# Using p-values as an effect size measure

Tags: p-value, monte-carlo, effect-size

In the following circumstance, I believe it is valid to use p-values as a measure of effect size: am I wrong?

1. I have a set of objects which have a single 'observed distance' from a given spatial location.
2. I have used a Monte-Carlo permutation test to randomise the location of these objects; on each iteration of the test a 'permuted distance' is calculated. The number of permutations (i.e. sample size) is the same for each object.
3. An empirical p-value is then obtained by calculating the proportion of permuted distances that are less than or equal to the observed distance.

I repeat this procedure for many objects, an obtain a distribution of empirical p-values. I would then like to analyse these p-values using a linear regression to look for predictors, and am treating the p-values as the 'strength of spatial association'. People are concerned that this is not legitimate, as p-values are not proxies for effect size - but in this case, as the same simulation procedure is used with the same sample size, surely they are?

Comment: P-values are random variables that depend on a lot of things, not all of which would necessarily what you are interested in (e.g. what makes you think they really measure spatial association?). Why would a p-value be a better effect measure than using e.g. the distances? If you do this many time, the observations from the "many times" will be correlated, how would you account for it? You may also have issues with linear regression assumptions (p-values being constrained to (0,1) etc.).

Comment: p-values and effect sizes are fundamentally, completely different things, even though they are closely related.  A p-value depends on a sample size whereas an effect size is a population property.  Perhaps by fixing a sample size you could use one as a proxy for the other, but there's not enough information here to determine whether that's possible or meaningful: your question is framed too abstractly.