# Can I use a p-value as my decision threshold estimate when calculating AUC-ROC?

Tags: r, p-value, modeling, roc

Sorry if the title is confusing. I essentially want to know if it's appropriate to use a p-value as the decision threshold (of the null outcome) when calculating AUC-ROC. I have a dataset of outcome values & a p-value associated with each one (generated via models that I've fit previously). I'm wondering if it makes sense to use the p-value as the decision threshold that gets varied when calculating AUC-ROC, provided of course that I specify the outcomes correctly.

I feel like this must be incorrect for some reason as it doesn't really vibe with my intuition around p-values. Would it maybe make more sense to use the effect size associated with the p-value instead (or even the adjusted p-value)? A simple reprex is below; we're assuming that the p-value refers to the null hypothesis that we cannot reject outcome **B** being correct vs. the alternative outcome **A**. The goal is to correctly classify the outcomes using the p-value / adj. p-value / test statistic as the decision threshold.

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(312)
model_df <- data.frame(outcome <- sample(c("A", "B"), size = 100, replace = TRUE), 
                       p_value = runif(100)) %>% 
            arrange(p_value) %>% 
            mutate(p_value_adj = p.adjust(p_value, method = "holm"))
yardstick::roc_auc_vec(truth = as.factor(model_df$outcome), 
                       estimate = model_df$p_value, 
                       event_level = "second")
```

I think this might be slightly related to [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/584749/using-p-values-as-an-effect-size-measure) about using p-values as effect sizes. I'll lastly note that I've seen the approach I detailed above used in bioinformatics papers before, which is why I'm considering it, but something just doesn't feel quite right.

Comment: I don't know anything about AUC-ROC, but p-values give you indices of the strength of evidence in the data against the null hypothesis, according to your statistical model. The smaller the p-value the stronger that evidence. If you want to form decisions on the basis of strength of evidence and you are using a constant model then using a fixed p-value threshold may be what you need. What is it that "doesn't feel right"?

Comment: Could you please give references for those papers using this technique? It makes no sense to me.

Comment: Here's an example - Fig. 3D-F in [this paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-020-14766-3#Fig3). The authors aren't explicit about how the curves were constructed, but I read the code used to generate the figures & essentially the approach I detailed above was used. The package used to generate the figures was [`iCOBRA`](https://www.nature.com/articles/nmeth.3805).